What is wrong with my animation retargeting algorithm?
Animation retargeting (also called motion retargeting) is the transfer of movement from one character to another in animation (i.e. from one skeleton to another), allowing the reuse of animation on different models.
I've been trying to implement this for weeks now without luck. The latest algorithm I wrote is the "best" so far, but is still very bad:

It takes all of the animation keyframes and orders them by time.
It loops over them, and for each ker, interpolates the source bone rotation/pos/scale at that keyframe time, transfers to world, then calculates the delta between it and the bind pose (in world), then we add that delta to target skeleton's bone bind-pose-in-world, then we transfer it to the local space of the target bone.


    public static AnimationClip RetargetAnimationClip<T>(
        this AnimationClip animationOfSourceRig,
        List<KeyValuePair<T, T>> rigsMapInBindPoses
        )
        where T : IReadOnlyName, IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        AnimationClip clipClone = animationOfSourceRig.Clone();



        List<AnimationNodeChannel> finalChannels = new();

        var sorted = SortKeyframesByTime(animationOfSourceRig.NodeAnimationChannels);
        foreach (var keyframe in sorted)
        {
            foreach(var map in rigsMapInBindPoses)
            {
                var src = map.Key;
                var dst = map.Value;

                if (keyframe.Channel.NodeName != src.Name)
                    continue;

                var idx = animationOfSourceRig.NodeAnimationChannels.IndexOf(keyframe.Channel);
                var modifiedChannel = clipClone.NodeAnimationChannels[idx];
                if(!finalChannels.Contains(modifiedChannel))
                {
                    finalChannels.Add(modifiedChannel);
                    modifiedChannel.NodeName = dst.Name;
                    for (var i = 0; i < modifiedChannel.RotationKeys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var rkey = modifiedChannel.RotationKeys[i];
                        rkey.Value = dst.Rotation;
                        modifiedChannel.RotationKeys[i] = rkey;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < modifiedChannel.PositionKeys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var rkey = modifiedChannel.PositionKeys[i];
                        rkey.Value = dst.Position;
                        modifiedChannel.PositionKeys[i] = rkey;
                    }
                }

                // get interpolated tree
                var srcInterpolatedAtKfr = Extensions.InterpolateTreeUpwards(src,
                    animationOfSourceRig, keyframe.Keyframe.TimeInTicks);

                var dstInterpolatedAtKfr = Extensions.InterpolateTreeUpwards(dst,
                    finalChannels, keyframe.Keyframe.TimeInTicks);

                switch (keyframe.Type)
                {
                    case KeyframeType.Position:
                        // We ignore position for now until we get rotation algorithm working
                        modifiedChannel.PositionKeys[keyframe.Index] = new(keyframe.Keyframe.TimeInTicks, dst.Position);

                        break;
                    case KeyframeType.Rotation:

                        var dstWorldRotBind = Extensions.CalcWorldRot(dstInterpolatedAtKfr);
                        var srcWorldRotBind = Extensions.CalcWorldRot(src);
                        var srcWorldRotKfr = Extensions.CalcWorldRot(srcInterpolatedAtKfr);
                        var srcWorldRotDelta = Quaternion.Inverse(srcWorldRotBind) * srcWorldRotKfr;
                        var dstLocalRot = Extensions.CalcLocalRot(dstInterpolatedAtKfr.Parent, dstWorldRotBind * srcWorldRotDelta);

                        modifiedChannel.RotationKeys[keyframe.Index] = new(keyframe.Keyframe.TimeInTicks, dstLocalRot);

                        break;
                    case KeyframeType.Scale:
                        break;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        clipClone.NodeAnimationChannels = finalChannels;

        return clipClone;
    }


Utility functions used:

    public static T InterpolateTreeUpwards<T>(
        T bone,
        IList<AnimationNodeChannel> NodeAnimationChannels, 
        float timeInTicks
        ) 
        where T : IReadOnlyName, IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        var channel = NodeAnimationChannels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NodeName == bone.Name);

        var position = bone.Position;
        var rotation = bone.Rotation;
        var scale = bone.Scale;

        if (channel != null)
        {
            position = AnimationPlayer.InterpolateVectorBetweenTwoFrames(channel.PositionKeys, timeInTicks);
            rotation = AnimationPlayer.InterpolateQuaternionBetweenTwoFrames(channel.RotationKeys, timeInTicks);
            scale = AnimationPlayer.InterpolateVectorBetweenTwoFrames(channel.ScaleKeys, timeInTicks);
        }
        // We don't return here if null because it could not have a channel but the parent has.

        T? parent = default; // null
        if (bone.Parent != null)
            parent = InterpolateTreeUpwards((T)bone.Parent, NodeAnimationChannels, timeInTicks);

        try
        {
            var @params = new object?[] { parent, bone.Name, position, rotation, scale }; // constructor
            bone = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), @params);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // todo: maybe custom error msg?
            throw;
        }

        if (parent != null)
        {
            var children = (ICollection<T>)parent.Children;
            children.Add(bone);
        }

        return bone;
    }


    // Equivalent of Unity InverseTransformPoint
    internal static System.Numerics.Vector3 CalcLocalPos<T>(T sourceBone, System.Numerics.Vector3 point) where T : IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        var worldPos = CalcWorldPos(sourceBone);
        var worldRot = CalcWorldRot(sourceBone);
        var relativePos = point - worldPos;
        var localPos = System.Numerics.Vector3.Transform(relativePos, System.Numerics.Quaternion.Inverse(worldRot));
        return localPos;
    }
    // Equivalent of unity calcWorldMatrix
    internal static System.Numerics.Vector3 CalcWorldPos<T>(T sourceBone) where T : IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        if (sourceBone.Parent == null)
            return sourceBone.Position;
        else
        {
            var parentWorldPos = CalcWorldPos(sourceBone.Parent);
            var parentWorldRot = CalcWorldRot(sourceBone.Parent);
            return parentWorldPos + System.Numerics.Vector3.Transform(sourceBone.Position, parentWorldRot);
        }
    }

    // Equivalent of Unity TransformPoint
    internal static System.Numerics.Vector3 CalcWorldPos<T>(T sourceBone, System.Numerics.Vector3 pt) where T : IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        var worldPos = CalcWorldPos(sourceBone);
        var worldRot = CalcWorldRot(sourceBone);
        return worldPos + System.Numerics.Vector3.Transform(pt, worldRot);
    }

    internal static System.Numerics.Quaternion CalcLocalRot<T>(T sourceBone, System.Numerics.Quaternion rotation) where T : IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        var localRotation = System.Numerics.Quaternion.Inverse(CalcWorldRot(sourceBone)) * rotation;
        return localRotation;
    }
    internal static System.Numerics.Quaternion CalcWorldRot<T>(T sourceBone) where T : IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        if (sourceBone.Parent == null)
            return sourceBone.Rotation;
        else
            return CalcWorldRot(sourceBone.Parent) * sourceBone.Rotation;
    }
    internal static System.Numerics.Quaternion CalcWorldRot<T>(T sourceBone, System.Numerics.Quaternion qt) where T : IReadOnlyTransform, IHierarchicalNode<T>
    {
        return CalcWorldRot(sourceBone) * qt;
    }

Here's a reference on the terminology used:

Here's the output animation for the current algorithm. I'm not sure what's wrong.


Is there a reason why you are inventing your own algorithm instead of using the build-in animation retargeting of Unity?

yes, i re-implemented an entire animation pipeline bc unity is so limited/bad. almost everything done except this. currently stuck on this one.

Found the solution finally.
the formula for calculating the retargeting i was using is wrong. the correct one should be:
targetBone.worldRotation = sourceBone.worldRotation * (baseSourceBoneRotation.inverse() * baseTargetBoneRotation);

where base rotations of both source and target armatures are sampled. doesn't need to be bindpose rotation. (but both poses need to be visually exact. ie. for example both in T-pose)
also, looping over sorted keyframes is the wrong approach, since it can happen that a child, when interpolating its tree, its parent interpolation is wrong because the future keyframe parentFutureKeyframe of the interval [parentLastKeyframe, parentFutureKeyframe] could be after the child's keyframe, thus will return wrong interpolation of the parent (since futureKeyframe is wrong/not yet processed)
the right approach, is to sort by hierarchy, looping over from the root (topmost parent) into the leaves bones.
